# Finding the $z$ coordinate for a point within a triangle in three dimensions.

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d, coordinate-systems

Suppose I know the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ for three vertices of a triangle and the x and y coordinates of a fourth point within the triangle.  How do I calculate the $z$ for that fourth point?

I've seen a couple other questions with answers but they did not clear anything up for me, such as this one: [Triangle in 3D space point X and Y coordinate know find Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852340/triangle-in-3d-space-point-x-and-y-coordinate-know-find-z)

A little clarification would be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Do you know how to find the equation of a plane given three points in the plane?

Comment: I would kind of just be shooting in the dark if I were to try anything, I wouldn't know if I were doing it right or got the right answer I just need someone with the equation to explain it a bit for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple technique using determinants (see [there](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Coplanar.html)).

Consider for example points
$$\begin{cases}A&=&(x_A,y_A,z_A)&=&(0,2,2)\\
B&=&(x_B,y_B,z_B)&=&(2,0,2)\\
C&=&(x_C,y_C,z_C)&=&(2,2,0)\end{cases}$$

which can be considered as vertices of a cube.

Let $M(1,1,z)$ belonging to plane $ABC$ for which we desire coordinate $z$.

The coplanarity of 4 points is equivalent to the fact that the following determinant is zero:

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_A&y_A&z_A&1\\
x_B&y_B&z_B&1\\
x_C&y_C&z_C&1\\
x_M&y_M&z_M&1
\end{vmatrix}=0 \ \text{giving here} \ \begin{vmatrix}0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&z&1
\end{vmatrix}=0 $$

giving a first degree equation for $z$. Technicaly: subtract the last column to the two first columns, one gets an easy expansion giving, as expected, the value $z=0$.