# Calculate Y coordinate of point in plane (triangle)

Tags: 3d

I need to find the y coordinate of a given point on a triangle in 3D space. If I'm not mistaken the equation for a plane is:
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}x-A_x & y -A_y & z-A_ z \\ B_x-A_x & B_y -A_y & B_z-A_ z\\ C_x-A_x & C_y -A_y & C_z-A_ z\end{matrix}\right|=0.
$$

So if I have the x and the z coordinate of a point on the plane and three points A, B and C which is on the plane how do I calculate the y of my coordinate?
Basically as far as I can tell, what I'm trying to achieve is to isolate the y coordinate. (Resulting in a an equation of the form: `y = ...`)
Can somebody help me out here? Thanks

I have found an answer where someone achieves basically what I want but for the z coordinate: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/851752/684967

Also extra points for pointing me in the direction of how to calculate this would be much appreciated. I would love to understand it! :)

(Here I'm talking an explanation of how to calulate the above. I'ts all greek to me)

Comment: See how to compute a matrix. What is a point on a triangle?

Comment: I've updated my question with a (hopefully) better description of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It is still not well defined - for every triple pair there are infinite y's that will allow you make a triangle.

Comment: Alright. I think I've done a poor job of explaining. I've included a link to a question that achieves some of the same i want here. And I've added an extra explanation to what I'm trying to achieve. But just to clarify. I know what A,B and C are when calculating the result. :)

Comment: Plug the x and z into the equation for the plan and solve for y.